# ServiceStack 4 Razor: no intellisense in Visual Studio 2013 with update 2

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013, servicestack, intellisense, servicestack-razor

I am running a Asp.Net Host (ServiceStack.Host.AspNet 4.0.30.0) - ServiceStack 4.0.30.0 project with Razor.

.Net Framework Target: 4.5.1

The project compiles fine, but I am not getting any intellisense in my Razor Views using Visual Studio 2013 with Update 2.

Any ideas on how to get intellisense to work in the ServiceStack Razor views?
My machine has MVC 4 and 5 installed as well.

[image]

Here is also a copy of my web.config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="true">
    <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
      </buildProviders></compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers></system.web>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="windows_consumer81_demo.Models" />
        <add namespace="windows_consumer81_demo.Models.Scenario" />
        <add namespace="windows_consumer81_demo.Localization" />
        <add namespace="System" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
        <add namespace="windows_consumer81_demo" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc" />
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DebugMode" value="true" />
    <add key="unsupportedRedirect" value="unsupported.html" />
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
  <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" /></appSettings>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `@model HomeScenarioResponse` try `@inherits ViewPage< HomeScenarioResponse>`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work either. I still get the intellisense error in the Razor view.

Comment: is this a new machine? maybe try installing [ASP.NET MVC3 with WebPlatform Installer?](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Razor-Notes#install-aspnet-mvc3-using-the-web-platform-installer)

Comment: I am running Visual Studio 2013, but it does not appear MVC 3 is supported in Visual Studio 2013 based on this MSDN link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)

Comment: Referenced text: Visual Studio 2010 SP1 supports only MVC 2 and MVC 3, Visual Studio 2012 supports only MVC 3 and MVC 4, and Visual Studio 2013 supports only MVC 4. For information about how to automatically upgrade from MVC 2 to MCV 3, see ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Upgrader. For information about how to manually upgrade from MVC 2 to MVC 3, see Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 2 Project to ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update. For information about how to manually upgrade from MVC3 to MVC 4, see Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: @Abe Is the solution then to use ASP.Net MVC 4 / 5?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the way it's supposed to work is that all the namespaces you add in `web.config` should have IntelliSense:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
    <namespaces>
    <add namespace="YourNameSpaceHere" />
    <add namespace="SomeServiceStackNameSpace" />
    . . .
```

Then in the .cshtml file you'd add:

```
@inherits ViewPage<YourModelClassName>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't always work. It compiles, but you don't get IntelliSense.

**However there is a fix:**

In your `.cshtml` file just type out the full namespace:

```
@inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage<Full.Namespace.Of.Your.Model.Class>
```

If you're using other classes, just add:

```
@using MyServer.ServiceInterface;
@using MyServer.ServiceModel;
```

**Another trick I recommend** is to strongly type your `@Model` object. Right there at the top, after the `@Inherits ViewPage<...>` stuff add:

```
@{
  Your.Class.Name TypedModel = Model; 
}
```

Feel free to rename `TypedModel` to something better.